# Ajax Call to servlet and load new page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to load an Ajax loader image on clicking the href link with id="test". After clicking this href I want to call a Jsp Servlet witch will sent an new request to load an new .jsp page.

The problem at this moment is that the servlet will be called, but he doesn't do an request to a new page. Can anybody help me out?

My code looks like this:

jsp page: href link and loader div

```
<div id="load"></div>
<a href="#" id="test" title="#" class="mainLink">link</a>
```

Servlet:

```
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
      // redirect to post
      doPost(request,response);
   }

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
      // send to new jsp page   
      request.setAttribute(getServletContext().getInitParameter("DynamicContentLoader"),"/secure/pages/test/testPage.jsp");
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/collector.jsp").include(request, response);
   }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#test").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "secure/TestController.do",  

        beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
            //show loading gif
            $('#load').addClass('loader');
        },
        success: function(){
           // nothing to do at this time
        },
        complete : function() {
           //remove loading gif
           $('#laden').removeClass('loader');
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

This is the part wich will include a new jsp page by the servlet responseDispatcher:

```
<c:when test="${not empty requestScope.includeJspContent}">
   <!-- start Dynamic Generated Context -->
   <jsp:include page="${requestScope.includeJspContent}" />
   <!-- end Dynamic Generated Context -->
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
   <!-- start no dynamic data found -->
   <jsp:include page="/error/no_dynamic_content.jsp" />
   <!-- end no dynamic data found -->
</c:otherwise>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many years left since I used JavaEE but as far as I remember the standard way to render jsp is to use `RequestDispatcher.forward()` method if you do not concatenate outputs. So maybe that's the problem too.

But what I can definitely see is that you just do not include your response whatever it is to your page. Add it to your `success` handler:

```
success: function(resp){
    $('#load').removeClass('loader');
    $('#load').html(resp);
},
```

Comment: I want to use an loader img to load an new jsp page. I will set the location of this page with the requestDispatcher.

Comment: I have include the part wich will show a new jsp page